# Magento Need to render discount before subtotal

Tags: php, xml, magento

I am having a incredibly hard time figuring this out. I created a area in checkout to render a customers discount. But I need it to render before subtotal

[image]

Below is my code

```
    <global>
        ....
                    <globaldiscount>
                        <class>winints/globaldiscount</class>
                        <before>subtotal</before>
                    </globaldiscount>
                </totals>
            </quote>
        </sales>
<global>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to sort the totals sort orders via the system configuration. `System->Configuration->Sales->Sales->Checkout Totals Sort Order`

[image]

Comment: "Global Discount" is a New discount I created. It has no configurations in the backend. I tried it and nothing changed.

Comment: Wasn't the exact solution but it definitely pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

hope this help

you can edit the phtml, and manually put what you want to show first

```
$totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getTotals(); 
//$totals will have subtotal, shipping, discount, total and tax value

if(isset($totals['discount']) && $totals['discount']->getValue()) {
  echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($totals["discount"]->getValue());
}
echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($totals["subtotal"]->getValue());
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend editing the template. I'd leave that down to `->renderTotals()`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @AdamPeterson answer, I was able to figure the issue out...

```
<default>
    <sales>
        <totals_sort>
            <globaldiscount>1</globaldiscount>
        </totals_sort>
    </sales>
</default>
```

He is correct that the ordering is based on the configs in the administration area but since my attribute is custom it was not there to sort. Magento sorts based on the title tag specified below

[image]

Once I applied `globaldiscount` under `totals_sort`, it finally changed the ordering.

you can of course extend your custom attribute to appear in backend, but I chose not to.